# Pasting text from clipboard to Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, browser, clipboard

I am using this function that pastes text from clipboard into multiple text fields.

```
function pasteFromClipboard(className) {
        var data = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
        if (data != null) {
            var cells = data.split('\n');
            var columns = $$('.'+className);

            for (i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
                if ( columns[i] != undefined ){
                    columns[i].value = cells[i];   
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This stuff that is attached to button via "onClick" works in IE, but not in FF or Chrome.
Now I know FF restricts access to clip, but I have manipulated the values in preferences with no success.

Can anyone help me out with this functionality, so it would work in Chrome?
Is there a `window.clipboardData.getData('Text');` similar option to make it work in FF and Chrome?

Comment: you CAN get the value of the CB once it's pasted, in both FF + Chrome https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent

Comment: so the solution would be another text field where the user pastes and the button then reads this field and copies the text where ever needed?

Comment: no, you bind all the inputs that can be pasted into with the handler, then grab the source via the e.getData("text/plain") method in the event argument, then set the value of each bound input to the source in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So I gave up on this some time ago.
I just created an additional `textarea` control, where I paste my stuff into.

Actions on page then read this control and do the work - then delete the content in this control.

Some would say its a clumsy solution, but i prefer "old fashion" and safe.

Best regards, no9.

Comment: seems about right.  if you look at typical working cut/paste solutions on the web, they often use https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard or something similar which uses flash under the hood - it gets around the differences between browsers.   of course, it requires flash which is it's own issue.